# How to use the message_tags parameter in the Post

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-graph-api

the documentation says

> object containing fields whose names are the indexes to where objects are mentioned in the message field; each field in turn is an array containing an object with id, name, offset, and length fields, where length is the length, within the message field, of the object mentioned

what's missing though is how do we need to encode it? should it be a JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, that's a read-only field for reading the list of pages/profiles tagged in a post, did you find documentation suggesting it was writeable?

Comment: no signs if it was read-only or not in the documentation. if so, is there any other way to tag pages or people in posts?

Comment: No, there's no way to add tags to posts via the API

Comment: Because when i checked for the purposes of answering this question we didn't have a writable API for tagging users in posts - unless it's changed since December 1 and I missed the update, this is still the case

Comment: FYI - it looks like Igy is from the facebook developer support team... thanks for chiming in here Igy. Your clarification on the FB docs is much appreciated!